# Windows 7 install rights standard user

Tags: windows-7, installer, standard-user

I'm in the process off migrating a legacy application that has been running under Windows XP to Windows 7.  This app pulls updates and setup installers for child components.  These are run under the user's non-admin account.  This of course works fine in XP but without admin rights in Windows 7 the app cannot run the installers (unfortunately this architecture is a requirement for the immediate term).

My question is how can I allow the users to run the installers? As this is a corporate environment giving these users admin rights is out of the question.  They are however a very specific set of custom applications so a broad allow any installer is not needed (and probably wouldn't be allowed).  It's my understanding that I can allow rights for specific directories and/or applications but I've had trouble finding out exactly how to do this.  Another option I've been looking at is changing the code to run the setup under elevated permissions but that would require me to have login credentials stored somewhere for the admin account.  I've been leaning to the first but would appreciate any thoughts on the matter someone might have.

Comment: Presumably this legacy application itself would require admin privs to be installed. If so, then why can't it also install these additional items while the process is already elevated?

Comment: The current process re-installs the applications as updates are pushed out to production.  Also if the user doesn't have rights to 'see' the application it never shows up as an option.  A manager (whom still is a standard user) logs in the morning and the app pulls any updates and reruns the installers.  Long story short they still need to exec the installers after the initial setup.

Comment: Sounds like something Microsoft's Server Update Services could take care of. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_Update_Services

Comment: @SiegmundNagel - Do these applications actually need to be installed to work?  Many applications once installed once don't need to be installed.  It sounds like you need to think about how this system works because as you have found it WILL NOT work going forward.  **Honestly what you used was a poor idea even when it did work.**

Comment: @Ramhound - I agree but it wasn't my design.  It's well over 10 years old.  Unfortunately it's huge and while a complete rewrite is in discussion it is not on the table at the moment.  I have to work within the current bounds with some leverage to make coding changes in the legacy code.  To answer your question yes the apps must be installed to work.  The legacy code has heavy usage of COM components that need registration.

Comment: Two suggestions: SuRun (very powerful, requires fine-tuning) and a homebrew app that governs the installation process and is allowed through SuRun, or use AD policies to advertise applications (won't work without MSI setups, of course, in many cases).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are configured with a domain.

You might consider creating a scheduled task using Group Policy to allow secure deployment of elevated credentials that can be used to give admin rights to your software.  At the very least that should work until you can get the code updated.

Take a look at [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725745.aspx)